# TypeScript node server setup. How to remove all *.d.ts files in dist folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json, rm

When I deploy my server I got errors

```
server_1    | (node:9) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /usr/app/packages/server/dist/modules/listing/create/resolvers.d.ts:1
server_1    | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { MutationResolvers } from '../../../types';
server_1    |                                                                      ^
server_1    | 
server_1    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

My solution(it works) is removing all `*.d.ts` files anywhere. Here is my `packages.json` script and its mass

```
    "build": "tsc -b && copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.graphql dist/ && rimraf ./dist/*.d.ts && rimraf ./dist/**/*.d.ts && rimraf ./dist/**/**/*.d.ts && rimraf ./dist/**/**/**/*.d.ts"
```

How can I remove all `*.d.ts` files in `dist` folder without folder nesting?

Comment: `**` should go as deep as needed. Does `rimraf ./dist/**/*.d.ts` alone work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this one

```
find ./ -name "*.d.ts" -delete
```